# Root level build.gradle is optional for multi-sub-projct gradle project?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, project

When using `gradle init` for creating a multi-subproject gradle project for java it does not create any root level `build.gradle` file. But when I am creating one manually it is being executed. So, my question is, is the root level `build.gradle` file is optional?

Root level `buid.gradle` is expected after `gradle init` as per my knowledge.

Comment: I asked this questing to discuss.gradle.org as well. There I got my answer. https://discuss.gradle.org/t/root-level-build-gradle-is-optional-for-multi-sub-projct-gradle-project/44349 . So, every build.gradle is just optional unless you really need it.

Comment: build.gradle is optional as per https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html